# How to create millions of directories using ForEach-Object -Paralell?

Tags: powershell, performance, powershell-4.0

I have a list/collection of 10s millions of directories that their length need to be reduced to meet a MaxLenghtPath before creating the new directory.

With a simple Collection | ForEach it takes a very long time, so I was hoping that using the Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 64 -Parallel using this code but still very slow about a thousand directories an hour.

```
    Clear-Host
$path               = "C:\a\15Mil.txt"
$Global:ParentDir   = "e:\!Data"
$MaxPathLength      = 220
$Global:MaxNumOfDirs          = 1000

$Global:NewPathList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object] 
$Global:ShortPathList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

$NewPathsArray      = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[string,object]]::new()
$ShortPathsArray    = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[string,object]]::new()

Remove-Item -Path $ParentDir -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-Item -Path $ParentDir -Force -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
$dirCount = 0
$NewPathList = (([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($path)))
$NewPathList = $newpathlist | get-random -Count $maxnumofdirs
$totalSeconds = (Measure-Command {
:ShortLoop ForEach($SubDir in $NewPathList)
{
    [int]$Chars2Remove  = $SubDir.length - $MaxPathLength
    If (($SubDir.Length -gt $MaxPathLength))
    {
        [string]$TopLevel           = "{0}\{1}\{2}" -f $SubDir.Split("\")
        [string]$Path2Shorten       = $null
        [string]$Path2Shorten       = $SubDir -replace([regex]::Escape($TopLevel))
            :RemoveCharsLoop For($c=1;$c -le $Chars2Remove;$c++)
            {
            [string]$MostRecurringChar     = (($Path2Shorten.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { !($_.ToString().Contains("\") ) -and ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_) }) |`
                                                Group-Object -NoElement | Sort-Object count -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Name
            [int]$RandIndex = ([regex]::matches($Path2Shorten,'[.$MostRecurringChar]').index | Select-Object -Last 100) | Get-Random -Count 1
            $Path2Shorten = $Path2Shorten.Remove($RandIndex,1)
            $ShortString = $Path2Shorten
                if (($TopLevel.Length + $Path2Shorten.Length ) -le $MaxPathLengthP)
                {
                    Break RemoveCharsLoop
                }

            }
        [String]$SubDir2Create      = $TopLevel  + $ShortString
        #}
    }
    else {
        [String]$SubDir2Create      = $null
        [String]$SubDir2Create      = $SubDir.ToString()
    }
    $ShortPathList.Add($SubDir2Create)
    If ($ShortPathList.count -ge $MaxNumOfDirs)
    {
        Break ShortLoop
    }

}
($ShortPathList | Get-Random -Count $MaxNumOfDirs) | ForEach{$null = New-Item -Path $_ -ItemType Directory -Force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
}
).TotalSeconds

###### Parallel routine  bellow ###### 
CLS
$path               = "C:\a\15Mill.txt"
$Global:ParentDir   = "e:\!ParalellData"
$MaxPathLength      = 200

$NewPathsArray      = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[string,object]]::new()
$ShortPathsArray    = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[string,object]]::new()
$NewPathsArray      = (([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($path)))
$NumberOfDirStrings = $NewPathsArray.Count - 1
$totalSecondsp = (Measure-Command{

0..$NumberOfDirStrings | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 128 -Parallel {
    $NewPathListIndex       = $_
    $SafeShortPathsArray    = $Using:ShortPathsArray
    $SafeNewPathsArray      = $Using:NewPathsArray
    $MaxPathLengthp         = $Using:MaxPathLength
    $MaxNumOfDirsp          = $Using:MaxNumOfDirs
    $ParentDirP              = $Using:ParentDir
    [string]$SubDir         = $SafeNewPathsArray[$NewPathListIndex].ToString()
    [int]$Chars2Remove      = $SubDir.length - $MaxPathLength
    If (($SubDir.Length -gt $MaxPathLengthP))
    {
        [string]$TopLevel           = ("{0}\{1}\{2}" -f $SubDir.Split("\"))
        [string]$Path2Shorten       = $null
        [string]$Path2Shorten       = ($SubDir -replace([regex]::Escape($TopLevel))).ToString()
        :RemoveChar For($c=1;$c -le $Chars2Remove;$c++)
            {
                $MostRecurringChar     = (($Path2Shorten.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { !($_.ToString().Contains("\") ) -and ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_) }) | `
                                            Group-Object -NoElement | Sort-Object count -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Name
                [int]$RandIndex = (([regex]::matches($Path2Shorten,'[.$MostRecurringChar]').index | Select-Object -Last 100) | Get-Random -Count 1)
                $Path2Shorten = $Path2Shorten.Remove($RandIndex,1)
                $ShortString = $Path2Shorten
                if (($TopLevel.Length + $Path2Shorten.Length ) -le $MaxPathLengthP)
                {
                    Break RemoveChar
                }
            }

        $SubDir2Create      = $TopLevel  + $ShortString

    }
    else {
        [String]$SubDir2Create      = $null
        [String]$SubDir2Create      = $SubDir.ToString()
    }
    $SafeShortPathsArray[$NewPathListIndex] = ($SubDir2Create)
    If ($SafeShortPathsArray.count -ge $MaxNumOfDirsp)
    {
        Break
    }


}
($ShortPathsArray |  Get-Random -Count $MaxNumOfDirs) | ForEach{$null = New-Item -Path $_ -ItemType Directory -Force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
}).TotalSeconds
Write-Host "the linear forloop took $totalSeconds seconds"
Write-Host "the linear forloop parallel took $totalSecondsp seconds"
```

Comment: Have you given any consideration to taking your chunking and processing those batches as ***parallel jobs***, vs what you have posted? Meaning, pass in an array of folders, looping thru those, waiting for the job completion, and retrieving the results. Poiutn of note, those graveyard marks (aka backtick) are not really needed where you have a pipe character. The Pipe is a natural line break as many other characters/operators in PS are.

Comment: The code for shortening for your path looks like it could be greatly optimized. Also, regex `'[.$MostRecurringChar]'` is broken (verbatim string - `$MostRecurringChar` won't be expanded. Finally, you can avoid calling `New-Item` for each and every dir. by using a delay-bind script block: `$null = ($ShortPathsArray |  Get-Random -Count $MaxNumOfDirs) | New-Item -Path { $_ } -ItemType Directory -Force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: @mklement0 The regex is working as is... but breaks when I remove the '[.]'. **How would you optimize the shortening routine?** I need to preserve the directory depth and the .SubString() path when you add the safeguards for not removing a full directory and not en up with "\\" takes a lot longer. As for delay-bind I need to check the number of directories that where created so I do not exceed the max number of directories.

Comment: @postanote I have tried the job option, but I was hoping that the Parallel option was more elegant and faster.

Comment: @mklement0 this is the actual New-Item routine ':DirCreation ForEach($Dir in $ShortPathsArray.Values){
    New-Item -Path $Dir -ItemType Directory -Force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if (($DirectoryCount % 100) -eq 0)
    {
        $DirectoryCount =  ([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories($RootDir,"*",'AllDirectories')| Measure-Object| ForEach{$_.Count})
        If ($DirectoryCount -gt $MaxNumOfDirs)
        {
            Break DirCreation
        }
    }
   }'

Comment: @Gt3pccb, I don't get the logic of your shortening routine. If you describe the desired behavior, I may be able to help. As for the regex: Yes, verbatim `$MostRecurringChar` as a regex won't do anything useful, but `[.$MostRecurringChar]` doesn't do what you expect either: it matches any of the following, verbatim characters:  `.`, `$`, `M`, `o`, .... As for the `New-Item` command: I don't get the logic there either, but note that `@([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories('.',"*",'AllDirectories')).Count` returns the count directly.

Comment: @mklement0  The shortening routine is supposed to match a..zA..Z0..9, get the recurrence of each character, and remove characters based on their recurrence. in a perfect string all characters would have an equal recurrence.  If you have a better way to do that can you kindly share it with me?

Comment: I suggest you ask a _new_ question focused just on that, where you can clarify the exact requirements, along with sample input and desired output paths. If you ping me here once you've created a new question, I'm happy to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a short thing regarding my comment.

```
Clear-Host
$jobs = (
'Get-Process', 
'Get-Service', 
'Get-EventLog -LogName Application'
).ForEach({Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($PSItem) & $PSitem} -ArgumentList $PSItem})

Get-Job -Verbose
# Results
<#
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Completed     False           localhost             param($command) & $co...
3      Job3            BackgroundJob   Completed     False           localhost             param($command) & $co...
5      Job5            BackgroundJob   Failed        False           localhost             param($command) & $co...
7      Job7            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             param($command) & $co...
9      Job9            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             param($command) & $co...
11     Job11           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             param($command) & $co...
#>

($results = ($jobs).ForEach({Receive-Job $PSItem -Wait -AutoRemove}))
```

Comment: I would use the threadjob module or powershell 7 foreach-object -parallel.

Comment: `($results = ($jobs).ForEach({Receive-Job $job}))` should be `$results = $jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemove`

Comment: Note that the OP is already using the preferable thread-based parallelism, namely the v7+ `ForEach-Object -Parallel`.

Comment: '@Santiago Squarzon', noted and posted the wrong block from my system test.

Comment: '@mklement0', also noted.

Comment: I have tried the AsJob and the big drawback is that lets say I assign lets say 100K directories, those directories would be processed sequentially. Would it not be true that -parallel will trigger a new "job" as soon as the number of running parallel jobs falls bellow the ThrottleLimit? Lets say that there is a directory "A" with 500 characters, the removal of excess characters will take a lot longer than a directory "B" with 250 characters, so "B" would be blocked until "A" finishes. With Parallel, "B" would not be blocked.

Comment: @Gt3pccb background jobs started with `Start-Job` do run in parallel, but in separate _child processes_, which makes them resource-intensive and slow. While there is no throttle limit, you may find that spawning an excessive number of child processes isn't feasible, which would require you to implement your own throttling logic. Unless you need full process isolation, there is _no_ reason to use `Start-Job` background jobs - _thread_-based jobs (`Start-ThreadJob`, `ForEach-Object -Parallel`) are superior in all other respects, so `ForEach-Object -Parallel` is as good as it gets in your case.

Comment: @mklement0 thank you. Is Start-ThreadJob better than ForEach-Object -Parallel?

Comment: @Gt3pccb, no: `ForEach-Object -Parallel` is a convenient, pipeline-based shortcut to manually creating multiple thread jobs with `Start-ThreadJob`.